# SQL Query :: parameters inside a Count?

Tags: mysql, sql

Let's say I have a table of movie renters with columns:

- UserID
- MovieID
- Rent_Start_date
- Rent_Due_Date

I am trying to achieve an output table that looks like:

```
[UserID, Count of Movies Due in 1 Day, Count of Movies Due in 1 Week]
```

Is this possible to do in one single query? I currently have a php script that runs 1 query on movies due in 1 day and another query that runs movies due in 1 week. These two queries are then looped for every user ID, filling in the table essentially slot by slot. This is kind of slow.

By attempting to create this output with only 1 query, I tried something like:

```
  SELECT UserID, count(movieID)
    FROM MovieTable
GROUP BY movieID
```

But this doens't create columns of counts of expiration dates.

Is it possible to create a count column that has an arguement such as count( //all those satisfy where `Rent_Due_Date - CURDATE() < ONE_WEEK`)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to group your results by user, not by movie:

```
SELECT   UserID,
         SUM(Rent_Due_Date BETWEEN CURRENT_DATE AND CURRENT_DATE + INTERVAL 1 DAY),
         COUNT(*)
FROM     MovieTable
WHERE    Rent_Due_Date BETWEEN CURRENT_DATE AND CURRENT_DATE + INTERVAL 1 WEEK
GROUP BY UserID
```

Comment: Won't this do a table scan?  Would it be more efficient to use two subqueries that pull all rows between those ranges and join them together in a master query?

Comment: @mellamokb: Depends on the indexes you have defined on the table.  I'd recommend having one at very least on the `Rent_Due_Date` column.

Comment: I don't think 2 queries would be more efficient with the current criteria, given that all the rows in the next day are also in the next week, so it is duplicating work. However it should be more efficient to add a `WHERE` clause limiting the results to the maximimum range of the count, in this case it would be `WHERE Rent_Due_Date BETWEEN CURRENT_DATE AND CURRENT_DATE + INTERVAL 1 WEEK`, then the second `SUM` column could just be `COUNT(*)`

Comment: Great I didn't know about Current Date and Interval. Thanks, i'll try this out.

Comment: I've ran into a bit of trouble with the dataset I'm using. I am getting some sort of double counting because there exists various instances of a userID renting the same movieID more than once.

I would like to add another feature that essentially only counts each Movie once per UserID. Similar to a distinct movieID, however since we are not selecting by movieID, I am unsure how to add this distinct feature.